# How to add id for react-credit-card-input in react.js

Tags: reactjs, credit-card

How to retrieve the credit card number from

```
<CreditCardInput
   cardNumberInputProps
   cardExpiryInputProps
   cardCVCInputProps

fieldClassName="input"
/>
```

using Id="creditnum"?

Comment: YOur query isn’t clear please be specific about the issue you are facing

Comment: @Think-Twice I think he wants to get a value from CreditCardInput, which is some type of input field. I believe he is trying to add an id to CreditCardInput so that he can get the element by id like in normal JavaScript: `document.getElementById("id")`.

Comment: @Tyler what you clarified..is exactly what I need..

Comment: @Tyler ok but what is CreditCardInput? Is it a library or his custom module? We should know this only then we can be able to help. The code he shared isn’t enough for us to help him with resolution he should atleast explain which library he is using

Comment: @Think-Twice it is a module

Comment: @ShagySHuuuSH what module? The module doesn’t have name?